# How to split a string in two, recursively

Tags: list, recursion, sml, smlnj, ml

I am writing a recursive ML function, that takes a string, and an index value, and splits the string at the given index. The function should return a list containing two strings.

I understand that I need two base cases one to check if the index has been reached, and one to check if the string is out of characters. I am stuck on how I assign the characters to different strings. Note, I used a helper function to clean up the initial call, so that explode will not need to be typed on every function call.

```
fun spliatHelp(S, num) =
  if null S then nil
  else if num = 0 then hd(S) :: (*string2 and call with tl(S)*)
  else hd(S) :: (*string1 and call with tl(S)*)


fun spliat(S, num) =
  spliatHelp(explode(S), num);
```

From an input of  spliat("theString", 3);

My ideal output would be ["the", "String"];

Answer (score 2):

For the `num = 0` case, you just need to return `[nil, S]` or (equivalently) `nil :: S :: nil`.

For the other case, you need to make the recursive call `spliatHelp (tl S, num - 1)` and then examine the result. You can use either a `let` expression or a `case` expression for that, as you prefer. The `case` expression version would look like this:

```
case spliatHelp (tl S, num - 1)
  of nil => nil    (* or however you want to handle this *)
   | [first, second] => [hd S :: first, second]
   | raise (Fail "unexpected result")
```

Incidentally, rather than returning a `string list` with either zero or two elements, I think it would be better and clearer to return a `(string * string) option`. (Or even just a `string * string`, raising an exception if the index is out of bounds.)